# Relative url in bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

My project structure like this:

```
Bobkhin.Web
    |- Common
        |- Js
        |- Themes
        |   |- Bobkhin
        |       |- Styles
        |- Styles
```

The `Styles` folder in `Common`, it just includes reset.css and some common css files and `Styles` folder in each theme folder includes css files for themes (I have a lot of themes, that why I seperate css files like this)

My code in BundleConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/common").Include(
            "~/Common/Styles/common.css",
            "~/Common/Themes/Styles/style.css",
            "~/Common/Themes/Styles/navigator.css",
            "~/Common/Themes/Styles/radcontrol.css",
            "~/Common/Themes/Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"
        ));
}
```

But when rendering, there's only `~/Common/Styles/common.css` is rendered and the others are not. I dont know why?

JFYI: I using spring.net to custom url